# sql does not order by order by with multiple variables and inner join in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, sql-order-by

I have the following statement in sql, to show data from my mysql database.

```
SELECT o.*
     , u.picture
     , u.socialid 
  FROM operaciones o
  JOIN users u
    ON o.id_usuario = u.socialid
   AND o.provincia = 'Cordoba' 
   AND o.divisa = 'Dolares' 
   AND o.fecha_op IN('27-06-20','26-06-20','25-06-20') 
 WHERE o.tipo = 'compra' 
 ORDER 
    BY o.cotizacion DESC
     , o.fecha DESC
```

The problem is that it returns the messy data, for example, the "cotizacion" part is from highest to lowest and it returns everything mixed, I already saw several questions but I could not solve it.

[image: result]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  You have an `ORDER BY`, presumably that does what you want.

Comment: Order by clause can be effected by other order by column, please give insert and create table scripts to analyze.

Comment: Always store dates using a date data type

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. "I already saw several questions but I could not solve it|" is not "reporting research" & is not helpful--everybody thinks they researched reasonably, and they didn't. ("Several" is nothing.) Report what you googled including in the manual & say what relevant things you learned & why it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current results make it look like `cotizacion` is stored as a string, not as a number. String wise, `'3'` is greater than `'22'` (because `'3'` is greater than the first character of `'22'`, that is `'2'`). You should fix your data model, and store numbers as numbers.

In the meantime, you can force numeric conversion like so:

```
ORDER BY 0 + o.cotizacion DESC, o.fecha DESC
```